# Timer javascript se acelera con cada reinicio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código de cuenta atrás:

```js
var tiempoTotalFinal = 63;
var Temporizador = tiempoTotalFinal;

var TiempoSesion=setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function CuentaAtras() {
Temporizador=Temporizador-1;


if (Temporizador <= 0) {
     clearInterval(TiempoSesion); //counter ended, do something here
     return;
}

var Porcentaje = ((Temporizador/tiempoTotalFinal)*100).toFixed(0);
$("#Avatar").removeClass();
$("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-"+ Porcentaje);

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = Temporizador + " segundos"; // watch for spelling
document.getElementById("timerpercent").innerHTML = Porcentaje + " %"; // watch for spelling
}

function ReiniciarTimer() {
 Temporizador = tiempoTotalFinal;
 clearTimeout(TiempoSesion);
 setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000);
}
```

```css
.avatar-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: none;
  background: #efefef;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.avatar-container .avatar {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}
.avatar-container .avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/**
* Function to generate procentual progress classes 
* .p-1 1% -> p-100 100%
**/
.p-1 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-2 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-3 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(100.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-4 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(104.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-5 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-6 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(111.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-7 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(115.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-8 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(118.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-9 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(122.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-10 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(126deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-11 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(129.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-12 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(133.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-13 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(136.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-14 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(140.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-15 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(144deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-16 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(147.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-17 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(151.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-18 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(154.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-19 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(158.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-20 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(162deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-21 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(165.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-22 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(169.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-23 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(172.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-24 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(176.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-25 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(180deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-26 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(183.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-27 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(187.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-28 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(190.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-29 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(194.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-30 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(198deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-31 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(201.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-32 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(205.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-33 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(208.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-34 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(212.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-35 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(216deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-36 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(219.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-37 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(223.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-38 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(226.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-39 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(230.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-40 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(234deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-41 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(237.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-42 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(241.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-43 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(244.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-44 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(248.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-45 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(252deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-46 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(255.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-47 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(259.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-48 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(262.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-49 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(266.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-50 { background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-51 { background-image: linear-gradient(-86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-52 { background-image: linear-gradient(-82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-53 { background-image: linear-gradient(-79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-54 { background-image: linear-gradient(-75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-55 { background-image: linear-gradient(-72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-56 { background-image: linear-gradient(-68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-57 { background-image: linear-gradient(-64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-58 { background-image: linear-gradient(-61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-59 { background-image: linear-gradient(-57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-60 { background-image: linear-gradient(-54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-61 { background-image: linear-gradient(-50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-62 { background-image: linear-gradient(-46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-63 { background-image: linear-gradient(-43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-64 { background-image: linear-gradient(-39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-65 { background-image: linear-gradient(-36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-66 { background-image: linear-gradient(-32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-67 { background-image: linear-gradient(-28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-68 { background-image: linear-gradient(-25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-69 { background-image: linear-gradient(-21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-70 { background-image: linear-gradient(-18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-71 { background-image: linear-gradient(-14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-72 { background-image: linear-gradient(-10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-73 { background-image: linear-gradient(-7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-74 { background-image: linear-gradient(-3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-75 { background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-76 { background-image: linear-gradient(3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-77 { background-image: linear-gradient(7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-78 { background-image: linear-gradient(10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-79 { background-image: linear-gradient(14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-80 { background-image: linear-gradient(18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-81 { background-image: linear-gradient(21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-82 { background-image: linear-gradient(25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-83 { background-image: linear-gradient(28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-84 { background-image: linear-gradient(32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-85 { background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-86 { background-image: linear-gradient(39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-87 { background-image: linear-gradient(43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-88 { background-image: linear-gradient(46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-89 { background-image: linear-gradient(50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-90 { background-image: linear-gradient(54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-91 { background-image: linear-gradient(57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-92 { background-image: linear-gradient(61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-93 { background-image: linear-gradient(64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-94 { background-image: linear-gradient(68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-95 { background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-96 { background-image: linear-gradient(75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-97 { background-image: linear-gradient(79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-98 { background-image: linear-gradient(82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-99 { background-image: linear-gradient(86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-100 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Avatar" class="avatar-container p-100">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mattchevy/128.jpg" alt="" class="avatar"/>
</div>

<span id="timer"></span>
<span id="timerpercent"></span>
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="ReiniciarTimer()">Reiniciar</a></p>
```

Resulta que cuando reinicio el setInterval con cada vez el tiempo va mas rápido.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar eso y que siempre un segundo dure un segundo?

Comment: Hola, el problema es que cada vez que presionas reiniciar se crea una nueva cuenta regresiva sin cancelar la anterior, luego estas están funcionando en paralelo haciendo que avance mas rapido

Comment: Y como cancelo la anterior? @the-breaker

Comment: si me das unos minutos te doy una respuesta

Comment: Claro :) @the-breaker lo que haga falta

Comment: En la función `ReiniciarTimer()` estás cerrando tu timer, pero con la función `clearTimeout()`... ¿no debieras usar `clearInterval()`, como lo haces antes?

Comment: Hace lo mismo si pongo clearInterval en vez de clearTimeout @quinqui

Comment: Uh, ok. Igual te recomiendo usar `clearInterval()`, ya que es la función apropiada para el `setInterval()`. Volviendo al problema, ¿no sería una alternativa que sea la función `ReiniciarTimer()` la que se ejecute tanto al inicio como al hacer click? Digo, así controlas bien que siempre se ejecute lo mismo...

Comment: Ni idea XD lo mismo si... No tengo muy claro como seria pero bueno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como había comentado el problema es que cada vez que presionas reiniciar se crea una nueva cuenta regresiva sin cancelar la anterior, luego estas están funcionando en paralelo haciendo que avance mas rápido.

Una solución simple es la siguiente:

Envía la linea `setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000);` fuera de tu función `ReiniciarTimer` y crea una variable tipo `boolean` llamada `sw` para controlar cuando funcione la cuenta regresiva:

```
setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000);
var sw=false;

function ReiniciarTimer() {
    Temporizador = tiempoTotalFinal;
    clearTimeout(TiempoSesion);
    sw=true;
}
```

Y luego en tu función `CuentaAtras()`coloca un if para que se ejecute solo cuando se requiera y que cuando llegue a 0 se detenga:

```
function CuentaAtras() {
if(sw){

Temporizador=Temporizador-1;


if (Temporizador <= 0) {
     clearInterval(TiempoSesion); //counter ended, do something here
     return;
}

var Porcentaje = ((Temporizador/tiempoTotalFinal)*100).toFixed(0);
$("#Avatar").removeClass();
$("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-"+ Porcentaje);

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = Temporizador + " segundos"; // watch for spelling
document.getElementById("timerpercent").innerHTML = Porcentaje + " %"; // watch for spelling
}
    }
```

Te dejo el código funcionando, saludos.

```js
var tiempoTotalFinal = 63;
var Temporizador = tiempoTotalFinal;
var sw=false;

var TiempoSesion=setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function CuentaAtras() {
if(sw){
Temporizador=Temporizador-1;


if (Temporizador <= 0) {
     clearInterval(TiempoSesion); //counter ended, do something here
     sw=false;
     return;
}

var Porcentaje = ((Temporizador/tiempoTotalFinal)*100).toFixed(0);
$("#Avatar").removeClass();
$("#Avatar").addClass( "avatar-container p-"+ Porcentaje);

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = Temporizador + " segundos"; // watch for spelling
document.getElementById("timerpercent").innerHTML = Porcentaje + " %"; // watch for spelling
}
}

function ReiniciarTimer() {
 Temporizador = tiempoTotalFinal;
 clearTimeout(TiempoSesion);
 sw=true;
}

setInterval(CuentaAtras, 1000);
```

```css
.avatar-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: none;
  background: #efefef;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.avatar-container .avatar {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}
.avatar-container .avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/**
* Function to generate procentual progress classes 
* .p-1 1% -> p-100 100%
**/
.p-1 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-2 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-3 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(100.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-4 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(104.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-5 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-6 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(111.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-7 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(115.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-8 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(118.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-9 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(122.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-10 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(126deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-11 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(129.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-12 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(133.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-13 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(136.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-14 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(140.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-15 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(144deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-16 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(147.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-17 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(151.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-18 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(154.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-19 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(158.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-20 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(162deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-21 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(165.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-22 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(169.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-23 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(172.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-24 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(176.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-25 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(180deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-26 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(183.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-27 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(187.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-28 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(190.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-29 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(194.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-30 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(198deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-31 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(201.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-32 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(205.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-33 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(208.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-34 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(212.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-35 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(216deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-36 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(219.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-37 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(223.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-38 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(226.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-39 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(230.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-40 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(234deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-41 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(237.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-42 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(241.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-43 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(244.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-44 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(248.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-45 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(252deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-46 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(255.6deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-47 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(259.2deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-48 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(262.8deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-49 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #efefef 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(266.4deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-50 { background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-51 { background-image: linear-gradient(-86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-52 { background-image: linear-gradient(-82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-53 { background-image: linear-gradient(-79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-54 { background-image: linear-gradient(-75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-55 { background-image: linear-gradient(-72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-56 { background-image: linear-gradient(-68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-57 { background-image: linear-gradient(-64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-58 { background-image: linear-gradient(-61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-59 { background-image: linear-gradient(-57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-60 { background-image: linear-gradient(-54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-61 { background-image: linear-gradient(-50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-62 { background-image: linear-gradient(-46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-63 { background-image: linear-gradient(-43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-64 { background-image: linear-gradient(-39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-65 { background-image: linear-gradient(-36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-66 { background-image: linear-gradient(-32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-67 { background-image: linear-gradient(-28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-68 { background-image: linear-gradient(-25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-69 { background-image: linear-gradient(-21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-70 { background-image: linear-gradient(-18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-71 { background-image: linear-gradient(-14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-72 { background-image: linear-gradient(-10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-73 { background-image: linear-gradient(-7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-74 { background-image: linear-gradient(-3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-75 { background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-76 { background-image: linear-gradient(3.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-77 { background-image: linear-gradient(7.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-78 { background-image: linear-gradient(10.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-79 { background-image: linear-gradient(14.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-80 { background-image: linear-gradient(18deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-81 { background-image: linear-gradient(21.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-82 { background-image: linear-gradient(25.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-83 { background-image: linear-gradient(28.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-84 { background-image: linear-gradient(32.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-85 { background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-86 { background-image: linear-gradient(39.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-87 { background-image: linear-gradient(43.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-88 { background-image: linear-gradient(46.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-89 { background-image: linear-gradient(50.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-90 { background-image: linear-gradient(54deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-91 { background-image: linear-gradient(57.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-92 { background-image: linear-gradient(61.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-93 { background-image: linear-gradient(64.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-94 { background-image: linear-gradient(68.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-95 { background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-96 { background-image: linear-gradient(75.6deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-97 { background-image: linear-gradient(79.2deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-98 { background-image: linear-gradient(82.8deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-99 { background-image: linear-gradient(86.4deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
.p-100 { background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0BF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0BF 50%, #efefef 50%, #efefef); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Avatar" class="avatar-container p-100">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mattchevy/128.jpg" alt="" class="avatar"/>
</div>

<span id="timer"></span>
<span id="timerpercent"></span>
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="ReiniciarTimer()">Reiniciar</a></p>
```

Comment: ¡¡Genial!! Muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: @Killpe de nada fue divertido